# Scanning Freemarker templates for XSS holes - is there already a tool for this?

Tags: maven, xss, freemarker, verification

As part of our build process, we have some basic shell scripting to scan our Freemarker templates for unescaped output, which could be a cross-site scripting vulnerability. I'm thinking of converting this to a proper Maven plugin.

The shell function looks like this:

```
check_unescaped () {
    if (find src -name '*.ftl' |grep -v '\.js\.ftl$' |xargs grep -lP '\${(?![^}]*\?(x?html|date|time(\?lower_case)?)\})' |xargs grep -L '<#escape' |grep -v '/test/'); then
        echo "Freemarker output found without template-wide escaping!"
        exit 1
    fi
}
```

Has anyone come across a tool that would already do this, or should I go ahead and write it?